# finding coordinates with derivatives

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find the coordinates of the point on the curve $x^2+xy+y^2=7$ where the slope is the same as at the point $(2,1)$.

I’ve already found $y’$ to be $\frac{(-2x+y)}{(x+2y)}$ and the slope at the point to be $-1$ but I don’t know where to go from there. Do I just set the derivative equation to be equal to $-1$ and solve?

Also when I found the derivative I got $\frac{(-2x-y)}{(x+2y)}$. I understand that you can make the equation negative and change the signs on the numbers but why does that only happen for the numerator? I think that’s an algebra question but I figured it was relevant.

Comment: Your first expression for $y'$ is incorrect and so the slope isn’t $-1$ at $(2,1)$. You have the correct one in the last paragraph, though. Why did you change it to the other expression?

Comment: This problem is likely meant to be an exercise in implicit differentiation, but you can solve it without using calculus by observing that the curve is symmetric about the origin.

Answer (score 1):

By implicit derivation we obtain

$$2xdx+ydx+xdy+2ydy=0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2x+y}{x+2y}$$

and at $(2,1)$ we obtain

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{5}{4}$$

and

$$-\frac{2x+y}{x+2y}=-\frac{5}{4} \implies 8x+4y=5x+10y \implies x=2y$$

that is

$$(2y)^2+(2y)y+y^2=7 \implies 7y^2=7 \implies y=\pm 1 \quad x=\pm 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the ellipse is centered at $(0,0)$, hence, the point $(2,1)$ is reflected to the point $(-2,-1)$ over the origin.